# Can I use a custom jQuery function not dependent on a selector for chaining?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I'm probably doing a jQuery faux pas here. Or a JavaScript one for that matter. So stop me if I am! :)

The scenario:

I want to create a function that takes in a string and perhaps some other parameters and then wraps them in a settimeout. Simple thing, but it's a lot cleaner than sticking settimeouts all over my code.

It'd look something like this:

```
function myFunction(text,interval) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do a bunch of stuff with the text var
    },interval)
}
```

Easy enough. Then I realized I might want to change this together multiple times and to do so, I'd then have to wrap my calls in a nested setTimeouts of their own, and I'm back to messy looking code.

So I was wondering if I could leverage jQuery to make this look better and more usable throughout my code.

I tried this, first making my own custom jQuery function:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function(text,interval) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do a bunch of stuff with the text var
    },interval)
}
```

Thinking I could then call it with something like this:

```
$('body')
    .myFunction('string1',1000).delay(500)
    .myFunction('string2',1000).delay(500)
    .myFunction('string3',1000)
```

This looks so much nicer and makes repetitive use a whole lot leaner. BUT...this doesn't work at all. My questions:

- am I even on the right path in thinking this is a viable use of jQuery and custom functions?
- if it *is* where am I messing up my logic?
- and finally, does one need to always choose a selector before calling chained jQuery functions? (I selected 'body' just to make the jQuery chain typical, but I'm obviously not doing anything in particular with that jQuery object)

**update**

Thanks to cookie monster's answer, I now have an updated example:

```
  $.fn.myFunction = function(text,interval) {
    return this.queue(function(next) {
         setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(text);
        },interval)
    })
  };
```

I'm then attempting it to calling it as such:

$.myFunction('msg1',500).delay(500).myFunction('msg2',500).delay(500).myFunction('msg3',500)

Doing that gives me this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$.myFunction()')
```

So I thought maybe it still needs a selector:

```
$('body').myFunction('msg1',500).delay(500).myFunction('msg2',500).delay(500).myFunction('msg3',500)
```

That works!...but just once. It executes the function once, but not again for the other 2 times in the chain. So, a step closer but I still think I'm missing some important concept or syntax.

**update 2**

JSBin of my <strike>*almost*</strike> working code: http://jsbin.com/exAyuCUp/1/

Comment: If it's not dependent on a selector, then why use jQuery at all? You could attach it to `$` as opposed to `$.fn` but that's just a normal function under the jQuery namespace. Also `delay` works if there's an animation queue.

Comment: @elclanrs to answer 'why use jQuery?' = I'm already using it, and I think this leads to a much more readable and reusable style for calling it as it's a function that's going to be used a lot in sequence in this particular project. Regarding `delay`, though...maybe that's one of the concepts I'm completely misunderstanding. Is `delay` only applicable to chaining jQuery animations?

Comment: Chaining is nothing special, you can make your own fluent interface without jQuery easily. In any case I think you're looking for promises as you're working with async code. jQuery has the [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: Thanks, @elclanrs. I wasn't aware of the deferred object. I'm not entirely sure that fits in to what I'm after, though. Is creating a queue-able chain of delayed function calls essentially asynchronous?

Comment: `setTimeout` is asynchronous, so I'd say yes. You're waiting for something to finish before doing the next thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you'd bother with doing the `setTimeout` when you can just use `$.fn.delay`.

I would just use a function without *any* delay:

```
$.fn.myFunction = function(text) {
    return this.queue(function(next) {
        // do a bunch of stuff with the text var
        console.log(text);
        next();
    });
}
```

and add `.delay` where needed:

```
$('body')
      .delay(500).myFunction('msg1')
      .delay(500).myFunction('msg2')
      .delay(500).myFunction('msg3');
```

If you don't need to select any element, you can still construct a jQuery object around something else such as a dummy object:

```
$({}).delay(500).myFunction('msg1');
```

(You cannot just use `$.delay(500).myFunction('msg1')` since the `$` object is not a jQuery object inheriting the `$.fn` prototype.)

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/XSv3w/)

Comment: Indeed using both the timer and delay as shown in the question is redundant. I can only guess that the code in the plugin requires a time for some sort of effect, and then an additional delay is (or may be) desired after that effect is done.

Comment: Yea, the setTimeout inside the function is a bit misleading/muddied. I should have omitted that from the examples. So...this certainly 'looks' like what I had in my head. That said, this appears to be pretty much what @cookiemonster has, but I'm having the same issue. It never actually calls the `console.log` statement. I don't get an error, but nothing is getting written to the console, either. I appear to still be missing a key bit of logic.

Comment: @cookiemonster Indeed, if `myFunction` does something less trivial than delaying the whole execution, you can't just factor the `delay` out. The OP stated: *I want to create a function that takes in a string and perhaps some other parameters and then wraps them in a setTimeout*, so in this case it suffices.

Comment: @DA. Have you checked the fiddle? Does it work for you there? How are you calling it? If needed, update your question with more details, perhaps with a fiddle demonstrating your updated problem.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens sorry, completely missed the fiddle link! Not a fiddle, but I put a jsbin of mine here: http://jsbin.com/exAyuCUp/1/ (am I just being stubborn not jumping on the fiddle bandwagon and sticking with jsbin? :) )

Comment: AHHH! SYNTAX ERROR ON MY PART. I was starting the chain with `$.fn.` when I should have been using an empty selector of `$({}).` as in your example. I think I have it working. THANKS!

Comment: I'm torn who to mark as the answer. You both contributed to the solution! So I have to flip a coin...Mattias, you're heads...and...HEADS! You get the answer. But thanks much to both of you!

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: Yeah, if OP is really just working with text and not elements, then putting the function on `$.fn` is the wrong approach from the start. Can't tell what OP is ultimately doing though.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.queue()` to make your code work with a `.delay()`.

```
start = Date.now()
$.fn.myFunction = function(text,interval) {
    return this.queue(function(next) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(text, start - Date.now())
            next() // This is mandatory!
        },interval)
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FkR2D/

> - *am I even on the right path in thinking this is a viable use of jQuery and custom functions?*

Yes, as long as there's a facility to manage an ordered execution of time delayed code, which jQuery does have.

> - *if it is where am I messing up my logic?*

Only thing missing was queuing your code, and retuning a jQuery object

> - *and finally, does one need to always choose a selector before calling chained jQuery functions? (I selected 'body' just to make the jQuery chain typical, but I'm obviously not doing anything in particular with that jQuery object)*

No, a selector simply performs a DOM selection. If you already have a set of elements in your jQuery object, there's no DOM selection needed.

Comment: Thanks! That's getting me headed in the right direction I think. I've updated my question using your examples. Alas, I still don't quite have it working.

Comment: @DA.: First issue I see is that you're never invoking the `next()` parameter when it's time for the next queued item to run,.

Comment: Indeed, the `next` is *critical* for the chain to continue.

Comment: @DA.: ...and your `undefined` issue is `$.myFunction('msg1',500)`. Your function is defined to work on a jQuery object, not on a property of the main jQuery function. While you don't need a selector if you already have a set of elements, you do need a jQuery object. If you don't need to operate on a set of elements, then your function probably shouldn't be on `$.fn`.

Comment: `$.fn` = aha! Thanks. That was definitely a bit of syntax I was missing. As for `next()` though, I've always understood that in the context of traversing through a jQuery object (created from a DOM node). I don't think I fully understand it in the context of the queue here. Do I need to add `.next()` to my chaining syntax?

Comment: OH! DUH! Completely missed the `next()` call in the sample code. Give me a minute...

Comment: @DA.: This isn't the `.next()` that's inherited by jQuery objects. This is just a function parameter that gets a function passed to it. You can call it `foobar()` if you want.

Comment: So, I'm at a point where if I add an alert *outside* the `return this.queue...` it gets executed. But not if it's *inside* it. It appears I'm still not understanding how to call the queue.

Comment: @DA.: Then check your console for errors. I can't tell what's wrong without seeing the code. But the key is that whatever code needs to be added to the queue needs to be in the callback. After that code runs, you call the `next()` parameter to invoke the next queued item.

Comment: @cookiemonster let me set up a jsbin example with real code! THanks for all the help thus far!

Comment: question updated with a link to some sample code here: http://jsbin.com/exAyuCUp/1/

Comment: @DA.: Your jsBin example seems to work fine. But if you're not operating on a set of elements, then why put your function on `$.fn`? In that case, you could use a "Deferred" object, or use one of the many async libraries that offer something similar.

Comment: @cookiemonster fair and good question. I need to read more about deferred objects to better understand when to use them and why. Another library could be useful too, but this entire app is already jQuery everywhere else so was the tool at hand.